# terraform saving output to file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform to gnerate certificates. Looking for information on how to dump pem  and cert values to disk file using terrafrom. here is the output variable. i want to dump them to  variable. any reference code snippet ??

```
output "private_key" {
  description = "The venafi private key"
  value       = venafi_certificate.this.private_key_pem
}

output "certificate_body" {
  description = "The acm certificate body"
  value       = venafi_certificate.this.certificate
}

output "certificate_chain" {
  description = "The acm certificate chain"
  value       = venafi_certificate.this.chain
}
'''
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

One way would be to use [local_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file). For example:

```
resource "local_file" "private_key" {
    content  = venafi_certificate.this.private_key_pem
    filename = "private_key.pem"
}
```

Comment: Will try this "local_file" resource. Cheers Marcin!

Comment: @CharlesD No problem. Glad I could help:-)

Comment: The problem is with "local_file" is the file that will disappear during "terraform apply"

Comment: @hbceylan I guess you meant `terraform destroy`

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question but let me drop my answer here incase anyone runs into thesame issue.
You can send all your outputs to a file like this

```
 terraform output > file.txt
```

where file.txt is the file that contains the outputs

Comment: what if the file hasn't been created yet? Will this command automatically create this file?

Comment: Yes it will create it.

Comment: This will output the entire content of the "terraform output" to the file.txt. In case if the requirement is for one or more of the individual output such as certificate body or private key, use the resource block as said above by @Marcin

Comment: This does not work with sensitive output. `terraform output -raw myvariable` outputs a single variable even if it is marked as sensitive. `terraform output -json` outputs all variables even if marked sensitive, as json.