# Terraform - module output to file with for

Tags: ansible, terraform, ansible-inventory, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-template-file

I create many VMs for which id are returned, my output looks like this:

```
output "master_id" {
  value = tomap({
    for k, master in cloudstack_instance.master :
    k => master.id
  })
}

output "worker_id" {
  value = tomap({
    for k, worker in cloudstack_instance.worker :
    k => worker.id
  })
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
master_id = tomap({
  "adm-1" = "0765b24e-1bd9-42a8-acf6-3463be494574"
  "adm-2" = "2a19ba2e-9aee-4a0a-aaf4-efdf228b6ab3"
})
worker_id = tomap({
  "wrk-1" = "643cbd23-0323-4738-9eab-d5c453772a37"
  "wrk-2" = "7b088d49-de02-4a67-bcb9-b18146a332d5"
  "wrk-3" = "c81761ae-23cc-4a47-b989-8d37574cc258"
})
```

I would like to save the result to a file using the template, unfortunately I do not know how to connect it in a for loop:

```
output "ansible_inventory" {
  value = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/inventory.tpl",
    {
????
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: 1. `master_id` and `worker_id` would already be Map type, and do not need the `tomap` function. 2. Please clarify how these outputs should be used and/or appear in your rendered template. It is unclear what you want to achieve with `????` in the argument for passing variable values to `templatefile`.

Comment: Additionally, based on your tags and the fact that the output is named `ansible_inventory`, you may want to check the questions and answers on SO about generating static Ansible inventories from dynamic Terraform outputs. You may find your solution in one of those.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63846090/9472275 Does this help? :D `local_file` resource

Answer (score 0):

I found answer myself:

```
data "template_file" "inventory" {
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/inventory.tpl")

  vars = {
    list_master = join("\n", formatlist("%s-%s ansible_user=root %s", var.prefix, keys(module.kubernetes.master_id), values(module.kubernetes.master_id)))
    list_worker = join("\n", formatlist("%s-%s ansible_user=root %s", var.prefix, keys(module.kubernetes.worker_id), values(module.kubernetes.worker_id)))
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "inventories" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo '${data.template_file.inventory.rendered}' > ${var.inventory_file}"
  }

  triggers = {
    template = data.template_file.inventory.rendered
  }
}
```